# Cropping a circular area in a photo

Tags: images, photos, gimp, crop

[image]

If you look closely , it has white borders all over ([see here](http://jsfiddle.net/fYmx6/)). Now my question is , is there any software (free) that can help me crop out the circular area of the button.

I have: Windows 7 with GIMP (though I can't find such feature in GIMP) and Paint (same again)

Comment: Yes, there are lots. You could use the eclipse tool of a paint program to highlight the area you want to keep, inverse and the delete the selection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [Paint.Net](http://www.getpaint.net/).

1. Open your image or copy it into a new image.

   [image]
2. Pick the ellipse selection tool.

   [image]
3. Place the cursor on the edge of the circle in the image:

   [image]
4. Press and hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> and drag the cursor to the opposite side of the circle.

   [image]

Depending on what you want to do, you might actually want to select everything *but* the circle. For that you can use the **Invert** selection.

[image]

To use it, first select *everything* by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and then performing the selection process as described above, in the Invert selection mode. Then you'll have everything but the circle selected.

If you then press <kbd>Del</kbd>, you end up with a clean button image:

[image]

Comment: I'd personally prefer the magic wand tool here. Let me throw together an answer using that instead

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: Magic wand doesn't produce a good result IMHO

Answer (score 3):

[image]

I prefer the magic wand - the trick being to lower the tolerance as low as possible to get a good result - I've used 10% but you can go as low as 1

Comment: As a side note to this answer, it always seems (to me anyway) that a tolerance of 27% is the sweet spot for most images

Comment: I tend to start low, and work my way up. Thats probably the case, I just lowered it from 50 to some suitably low number, saw it was good enough and left it there.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you certainly *can* do it on GIMP. There's an ellipse tool as well:

[image]

It's very similar in selecting to paint.net, but you can also change the area of the selection after selecting it the first time --maybe to make fine adjustments-- by clicking and dragging your mouse over the squares appearing when you hover your mouse over the vertices or rectangles when it's over the edges of the square guide:

[image]

And zoom in if necessary:

[image]

After that, you can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (Invert selection or do "Select" > "Invert Selection" from the menubar to select everything outside the ellipse, then press <kbd>Delete</kbd> to remove the unneeded part:

[image]

The checked grey pattern indicates that these parts are transparent. If you don't see this, go to "Layer" > "Transparency" > "Add Alpha Channel" and press delete again without deselecting the current selection.

Now your image is ready to be exported as png :)